# DataDag Kafka Monitoring - install-tools now working

Tags: go, datadog

I am trying to setup DataDog Kafka Monitoring setup.

I am following the steps prescribed in their document:

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-kafka-with-datadog/

But I am getting error while I am running this command:

```
sudo invoke install-tools
```

Output:

```
/bin/bash: go: command not found
```

But GoLang installed and I am getting by

```
go version
```

Output:

```
go version go1.17.7 linux/amd64
```

Comment: Run `sudo go version` instead

Comment: You are right, go version , I am getting, sudo go version saying no go command. But what should I do to get sudo go version to work.

Comment: Edit the /etc/profile file to modify the system PATH